# How do I build a Clock using setInterval and clearInterval?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to Write a `SecondClock` class, with two methods: `start` and `reset`.​

In the `start` invocation, the callback gets invoked every second on the "seconds hand" of the clock. Always start with 1 and don't utilize the seconds value of the current computer clock time.

The first "tick" with value 1 occurs 1 second after the initial "secondClock" invocation.

The second "tick" with value 2 occurs 2 seconds after the initial "secondClock" invocation.

and so on.

Upon `reset` invocation, completely stops the "clock".
Also resets the time back to the beginning.
​

```
class SecondClock {
  constructor(cb) {
    this.cb = cb;
    this.IntervalId;
    this.tick = 'tick';
  }

  start(tick){
    this.IntervalId = setInterval(this.cb(tick),1000);
  }

  reset(){
    clearInterval(this.IntervalId);
  }
}

// Border Line
const clock = new SecondClock((val) => { console.log(val) });
console.log("Started Clock.");
clock.start();
setTimeout(() => {
    clock.reset();
    console.log("Stopped Clock after 6 seconds.");
}, 6000);
```

I am able to start the clock and this is what I see in the console:

```
'Started Clock.'
undefined
Type Error on line callback is not a function at blob: callback is not a function
Type Error on line callback is not a function at blob: callback is not a function
Type Error on line callback is not a function at blob: callback is not a function
Type Error on line callback is not a function at blob: callback is not a function
Type Error on line callback is not a function at blob: callback is not a function
Type Error on line callback is not a function at blob: callback is not a function
'Stopped Clock after 6 seconds.'
```

Which should Ideally be:

```
'Started Clock'
1
2
3
4
5
6
'Stopped Clock after 6 seconds.'
```

1. Is there any way I can leverage the Date() class to accomplish this?
2. After I invoke the `setInterval` via `clock.start()` statement, I am able to invoke `clearInterval` after 6 seconds.
3. I am assuming `this.cb(this.tick)` is able to fetch `this.tick` only once. But after `this.cb(this.tick)` is pushed into callback queue, the error is seen.
4. Printing 'tick' instead of numbers was my first milestone. Further, I plan to implement it with counter is what I assumed. But clearly, I found it hard to implement even with 'tick'.
5. Would prefer to not to change anything below the border line.

Comment: What problem are you having? There doesn't seem to be a question here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the pointer you need is that `setInterval` or `setTimeout` should take a function as a first argument.

```
setInterval( this.cb(x) , 1000 )   //unless this.cb returns a function this wont run
```

**Option 1:** create an anonymous function

```
var _helper = function(){
    myLogic(10);
};
setInterval (_helper, 1000);//first argument is a function
```

**Option 2:** your cb can return a function

```
var cb = function(x){
    return function(){ 
        //logic or side-effect
    };
};
setInterval (cb(10), 1000); //first argument is still a function
```

**Option 3:** Possibly by using promises/resolve

Comment: Option 1 helped.

Just that I created a arrow function in the place of `this.cb(tick)`. I instead replaced with `()=>{this.cb(this.tick++)}` and `let this.tick = 0`